# Spark streaming with Checkpoint

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am a beginner to spark streaming. So have a basic doubt regarding checkpoints. My use case is to calculate the no of unique users by day. I am using reduce by key and window for this. Where my window duration is 24 hours and slide duration is 5 mins. I am updating the processed record to mongodb. Currently I am replace the existing record each time. But I see the memory is slowly increasing over time and kills the process after 1 and 1/2 hours(in aws small instance). The DB write after the restart clears all the old data. So I understand checkpoint is the solution for this. But my doubt is

What should my check point duration be..? As per documentation it says 5-10 times of slide duration. But I need the data of entire day. So it is ok to keep 24 hrs.

Where ideally should the checkpoint be..? Initially when I receive the stream or just before the window operation or after the data reduction has taken place.

Appreciate your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In streaming scenarios holding 24 hours of data is usually too much. To solve that you use a probabilistic methods instead of exact measures for streaming and perform a later batch computation to get the exact numbers (if needed).

In your case to get a distinct count you can use an algorithm called [HyperLogLog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog). You can see an example of using Twitter's implementation of HyperLogLog (part of a library called [AlgeBird](https://github.com/twitter/algebird)) from spark streaming [here](https://gist.github.com/MLnick/4761966)

Comment: Thank you for responding. So trying to solve entire chain using streamingwill not be a coorect approach.?  Would it be better if i split the job with spark streaming and another spark job which runs periodically..?                                 Regarding distinct counts.  since we need to get the unique users by day. We collect the users using a window, then use countApproxDistinctByKey, which i understand uses HyperLogLog internally.

Comment: If you'd look at the code sample you'd see that it calculated estimate for each batch (i.e. smaller window that you calculate) and a global one (which in your case would be the full day) . This isn't like holding all the data so it can be summarized